# Added angular project into a current ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, angular

i am having a problem which i want to combine my old ASP.net website into  a new web project but i want to remain my current ASP.net backend. And its mean i just want to change the front end only for this thing.

The front end that i want to try is using the Angular JS, but soon i found out that wasnt easy to setup for this project. 
Because when have angular project it need to build only can work, so how do i have the project to star this new front end. I not clear what should i start as a correct way.

Or it must separate to a new project and redo the front end and backend?

Answer (score 1):

Angular usually uses REST calls to communicate with the back-end. With ASP.NET the back-end renders the page and sends the complete HTML page to your browser. In Angular your browser renders the incomplete HTML page and then fill it with the result from your REST call.

In your case you will have to add a REST layer to your back-end. Then you can create an Angular project which calls this REST layer. So these are 2 seperate projects.

These are some usefull links that might help you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

Comment: But i already have the current ASP.net as backend, if like this, how do i get the connection between this both? Cause what i know is if another angular project it will need to build only can get the files.

Comment: Not yet, now i want to create a new one, just not sure how to build it correctly.

Comment: Ah allright. If you click on the first link in my answer (the docs.microsoft one) you will find a tutorial how to setup a REST api. This REST api will provide angular with your data.

Comment: But i try to understand what you have told me, just not sure if going to change is that a huge work load to change the ASP.net back to the REST API.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite anything if you followed the SOLID principles. You just need to add a new REST layer which calls your methods.